# Sitecore extranet & field access rights

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is there any way to restrict access to a specific field on an item in Sitecore? We have a setup where an anonymous, non-authenticated user should be allowed to read one field *("FreeContent")* and any authenticated user should see another field *("FullContent")*. Setting Field Read / Item Read to deny in the template editor does not work, I'm guessing because the security then applies to that portion ("the field") of the template, not the content item itself.

We could, of course check if the user is authenticated and set the Field property of the  control to *"FreeContent"* but we'd really like to be able to control from Sitecore which fields are open to all and which are not.

Is it possible at all, or do I need to implement this myself?

Answer (score 1):

You were doing it right - Field read/write settings on the data template is how to set access to specific fields in items.

[See p14](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/securityreference-usletter.pdf).

You might need to republish the site and clear caches etc.

Otherwise check with the access viewer to make sure your various roles have correct access.

Comment: Ok, so the Field Read access is denied through the data template, just as I thought, this however does not prevent the extranet (extranet\Anonymous) user from reading the field. The CanRead property is False when checking it but the sc:text control allows for the field to be rendered to the client, why is this?

Comment: Have you explicitly denied access to field read on the template for the extranet/Anonymous account? I was under the impression that the sitecore field controls were fully integrated with the security model but reading around I cant see that stated as a certainty anywhere. I suppose it's also possible that it's a version bug for whichever version you have....